# Insert custom characters and move mouse pointer to certain position

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I face some issue when trying to **add custom** key-blinding under **Sublime Text 3**.

1. Go under Under **Preferences->Key Binding- Users.**
2. Add { "keys": ["alt+k"],  "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "d();"}}
3. When i Press **Alt+k** will return me this **d();** <-Mouse Pointer end after the semicolon

What i wish to achieve is something like **d(Pointer);** after press **Alt+k** <-Mouse Pointer within the braces.

I try figure out some key-Binding Style in the default one but cant find any useful.

PS:I know "command": "move" able to move pointer position but how to combine this with insert,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive this behavior without chaining commands with a snippet. Just use this keybinding:

```js
{
    "keys": ["alt+k"],
    "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {
        "contents": "d($0);"
    }
},
```

Where `$0` defines the cursor position. You can even use `${0:$SELECTION}` to optionally surround the selected text.

To address your PS: If you are interested in chaining commands, then the [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) package could be interesting for you.

Comment: Wow excellent for insert_snippet and [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) package.

Btw i don't get the meaning of ${0:$SELECTION},can you explain more . thanks

Comment: You can use the snippet `d(${0:$SELECTION});` instead of `d($0);`. If you select text and press `alt+k`, then the selected text will be inside the parens instead of replaced by `d();`.

Comment: understand , no wonder they say sublime is so beautiful ..thanks.